# Proving $X^p-1=\prod_{j=0}^{p-1}(X-(e^{2\pi i/p})^j)$ for an odd prime $p$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, proof-writing

Basically just the thing in the title. Like, intuitively I understand it to be true. Both sides of the equation have the same zeroes and all, but I don't know how to prove this rigorously. I've tried expanding in multiple ways, but none of them were promising. Can someone help me with how to tackle this?

Comment: The two polynomials not only "have the same zeroes" but they are both of equal degree $p$ and all the $p$ shared roots are distinct.  That is more than enough to imply they are equal (as complex polynomials).

Comment: If you really want to carry out the computation, it will simplify the calculation if you pair up the complex roots which are conjugates and multiply those two linear factors to form a *real* quadratic polynomial.  But it isn't necessary to do that; consider showing their difference is the *zero polynomial* instead.

Comment: @hardmath Hm, I see. Though, considering their difference only feels like shifting the problem, because I still can't see how that is going to equal to zero. And about your first comment, it still feels a bit "handwavy" or something. How should I phrase this as a proof if I'll go with that route?

Comment: Would converse Vieta's theorem also be hard?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\zeta_p = \mathrm{e}^{2\pi\,\mathrm{i}/p}$ to simplify notation.  Substitute each element of $\{0, \zeta^0, \zeta^1, \zeta^2, \dots, \zeta^{p-1}\}$ for $X$ into the polynomials on each side of your equation.  See that these two polynomials of degree $p$ agree on $p+1$ points, so are identical.  (Example proof of this last fact [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Uniqueness_of_the_interpolating_polynomial).)

Comment: You also need to use that both polynomials are monic. Otherwise $x+1$ and $2x+2$ have the same roots and degrees, but are not equal.

Comment: @user158834 : That would be true if we only had $p$ points of agreement.  Since we have $p+1$ points of agreement, the potential scalar multiple distinction is also excluded.

Comment: That is true. I did not count the points correctly.

Comment: @EricTowers Thank you very much!